# C# Regex for extraction of specifik numbered patterns from string

Tags: c#, regex, string, search

I've managed to extract numbers with specific patterns like this: "F2020-53, 2020-54, 2020-56 John Doe" where I get "2020-53" and "2020-54" and "2020-56", when using

```
Regex fakturaMultiPattern = new Regex(@"(\d{4}-\d+)+");
```

But I've not been able to extract patterns like this: "F2020-53/54 John Doe" where I want to extract the "2020-53/54". I've tried with:

```
Regex MultiSlashPattern = new Regex(@"^\d{4}-\d+/\d+");
```

I think, I'm close, but please help!

Comment: Have you tried removing `^` from the beginning of the regex?

Comment: Yes, I have. I should have told that I use the Split() method so the ^ anchor should be there. The problem must be related to the "/\d+" which was appended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you expect:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Reginator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testString = @"F2020-53/54, 2020-54, 2020-56 John Doe";
            var matches = GetMatchedCollections(testString, @"([,]?[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\/[0-9]+|[,]?[0-9]+-[0-9]+)");

            Console.WriteLine(matches[0].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(matches[1].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(matches[2].ToString());

            // Output:
            //      2020-53/54
            //      2020 - 54
            //      2020 - 56
        }

        public static MatchCollection GetMatchedCollections(string stringToSearch, string pattern)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return regex.Matches(stringToSearch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It most certainly did - thank you my friend. I really need to sit down and spend some hours learning a bit more about regular expressions

Comment: No worries. If happy with it please don't forget to mark as solution.

Comment: I feel stupid, where do I mark it as solvled ??

Comment: No worries. There is a tick sign to the left of the above code. You only see it. :)